# Android MediaCodec Decoder: Slow Down Video Playback

Tags: android, video, android-video-player, android-mediacodec

I've searched but still can not find the answer.

I'm making a simple video player using androids MediaCodec (using decoder and surface) in API 21. But, The Video is playing very fast. How I can play the video at normal speed?

Here is my code:

```css
package com.bd.mediacodec;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo;
import android.media.MediaCodec.CodecException;
import android.media.MediaExtractor;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class DecodeActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
 private static final String SAMPLE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/video.mp4";
 private Surface surface;
 private MediaExtractor extractor;
 private MediaCodec decoder;
 boolean isEOS = false;
 long extractorSampleTime = 0;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(this);
  sv.getHolder().addCallback(this);
  setContentView(sv);
 }

 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
  
  extractor = new MediaExtractor();
  try {
   extractor.setDataSource(SAMPLE);
  } catch (IOException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
   MediaFormat mediaFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
   String mime = mediaFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
   if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
    extractor.selectTrack(i);
    try {
     decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    surface = holder.getSurface();
    decoder.configure(mediaFormat, surface, null, 0);
    break;
   }
  }

  if (decoder == null) {
   Log.e("DecodeActivity", "Can't find / Open Video");
   return;
  }
  // Adding Callback
  decoder.setCallback(mDecoderCallback);
  decoder.start();        
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
  
  decoder.stop();
  decoder.release();
  extractor.release();      
 }

 MediaCodec.Callback mDecoderCallback = new MediaCodec.Callback() {
  
  @Override
  public void onOutputFormatChanged(MediaCodec codec, MediaFormat format) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index,
    BufferInfo info) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // Release output buffer.
   codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index, true);              
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   if(!isEOS){
    ByteBuffer buffer = codec.getInputBuffer(index);
    int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
    if (sampleSize < 0) {
     
     Log.d("DecodeActivity", "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
     decoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
     isEOS = true;
    } else {
     extractorSampleTime = extractor.getSampleTime();
     decoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, sampleSize, extractorSampleTime, 0);
     extractor.advance();
    }
   }             
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onError(MediaCodec codec, CodecException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
  }
 };
 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a pair of simple video players in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), one for SurfaceView, one for TextureView.  They both use use the [SpeedControlCallback](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/SpeedControlCallback.java) class to manage the playback speed.  The key is to use the presentation time stamp for each frame to determine how long to wait before displaying the next frame.

Using a fixed value for the playback speed only makes sense if the video uses a fixed frame rate.  See the generated movies in Grafika for an example of variable-frame-rate video.  One of the players has a "play at 60fps" button that causes the player to ignore the timestamps so you can observe the difference.

BTW, putting the playback loop inside `surfaceChanged()` is not a good idea.  Use the callbacks to trigger activity, don't build the entire player inside them.

Comment: Very good point. I will check the link. If good, I'm going to Accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Don't Know whether it is the Best solution or not.

From the `mediaFormat`, I extracted `captureRate`

```
captureRate = mediaFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE);
```

Then,

```css
  @Override
  public void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index,
  BufferInfo info) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Release output buffer.

    codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index, true);
    try {

      Thread.sleep((int)1000/captureRate);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't just setting PresentationTimeUs on bufferInfo instead of doing that work better? `info.PresentationTimeUs *= slowRatio;` Just an idea. Not sure if it fits the context. But I've seen that the presentation time is the only value that determines when a frame is shown, and that you can play with it anytime in a decoding / encoding process.